# What are the requirements to use a certificate to sign a sideloading app in VS2017?

Tags: uwp, code-signing

I developed a UWP on VS2019 and manage to sign everything for sideloading.

Downgrading to VS2017 I can't sign the package.
I can debug and use temporary certificates but I can't use the production certificate.

I keep getting this:

```
Failed to sign 'D\Package.appx'. SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try `Store -> Create app packages...` and then re-select the certificate during the wizard flow?

Comment: The wizard would not "ask" for a certificate selection. I reinstalled the certificate on the machine and I removed the timestamping part that was still in the csproj, and that made it work.